# Minio - bucket usage count not updating

Tags: minio

I'm running MinIO via Docker (version 2022-04-16, so it could do with being updated). I have a handful of buckets used to store backups. Each bucket containers a handful of date stamped folders, each with 1 or 2 large (10GB+) files inside.

In the MinIO Console, the bucket usage is showing what I think may be peak usage. Deleting data via the Console doesn't seem to reduce the usage figures at all. One bucket is now empty, but still showing 2.2TiB of usage.

Is there a way to update these counts? Is there a cron task or similar that I'm missing?